# Summation series in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am Unable to get the answer to:
SS=Sigma n=1 to k 1/k^2.
for n = 2000.
Try to find an exact solution for n = ∞ in the literature. Then determine how many
terms you need to get a result which has four correct decimals of the theoretical
result.
Can any of you suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: As for the exact solution: this is known to be `pi^2/6`. Anyway, this would be more suited to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you trying to do this with symbolic math in Matlab or are your trying to write program using numerical methods? This looks like a homework question, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find the limit value: [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

For the 4 digits problem I had to write a Ruby program:

```
29353: 1.6448999993605375, 3.4067487688860254e-05
29354: 1.6449000005210916, 3.4066327134762986e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
termvec = [];
for ii = 1:2000
   termvec = [termvec; 1/ii^2];
end
sum(termvec)
```

And to find how many terms you need to sum till the difference between the summation and the limit value is smaller than some arbitrary amount:

```
limitval = pi^2 / 6;

termvec = [];
ii = 1;
while abs(sum(termvec) - limitval) > 0.00001
   termvec = [termvec; 1/ii^2];
   ii = ii + 1;
end
disp(ii)
```